# ActionScript library to convert Markdown to HTML

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, markdown

I'm currently working on a Flex 3.0 project in which I have to display some input text with minimum formatting.

We are considering to use "markdown" as the chosen way to express this formatting, now I would like to know if there is a library for this purpose.

Answer (score 9):

You could use [my AS3 port](http://gist.github.com/648771) of [John Fraser's Showdown](http://attacklab.net/showdown/).

```
// Usage:
var text = "Markdown *rocks*.";
var html = Showdown.makeHtml(text);

// <p>Markdown <em>rocks</em>.</p>
```

Comment: @Franky-D: Sure thing. The real kudos go to John Fraser and John Gruber. If you diff my Showdown.as against showdown.js, you'll see that I had to change very little to make it valid AS3.

Comment: I can't believe I'm referring to this in 2016.

Comment: 2019 and still needed! :) Had to edit it a bit in order to get rid of few errors in "Flash IDE" for AIR, but seems to be working.