# Is there an AS3 or Flex library for high quality rendering some mainstream text markup language?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, markup, bbcode

I wish to allow content input in some Flex app I'm developing, using a markup language - Wiki markup / bbcode / similar.

I'm looking for some library to render in high quality such markup.

Comment: I voted to close as I feel this is overly broad.  I think to get a concrete answer, you really have to ask a specific question.  I, personally, do not find "some mainstream text markup" to be specific enough.  You may try being more definitive in what you want to do; possibly referencing the formal standard you wish to implement, if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820212/actionscript-library-to-convert-markdown-to-html) -

You could use [my AS3 port](http://gist.github.com/648771) of [John Fraser's Showdown](http://six.pairlist.net/pipermail/markdown-discuss/2007-February/000543.html).

```
// Usage:
var text = "Markdown *rocks*.";
var html = Showdown.makeHtml(text);

// <p>Markdown <em>rocks</em>.</p>
```

Comment: You're link to John Fraser's Showdown gives a 404 error for me and the domain appears to relate to starting home based businesses.